# C++ pass parameter by rvalue reference if possible, otherwise copy the lvalue reference

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, rvalue-reference

With rvalue references, many redundant copies may be elided, but that seems to require me to write the same function multiple times (one for an rvalue reference, one for a `const` lvalue reference).  But the standard library seems to only need to declare some functions once.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

void foo(int&& x){
    x = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    foo(x); // compile error
    std::make_tuple(x); // ok
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Calling `foo(x)` is a compile error, because I cannot convert implicitly from `int` to `int&&`.  But I am perplexed as to why `std::make_tuple` would work.  The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) says that it only accepts rvalue reference parameters.  It also seems to not make copies when the value passed into it is an ravlue reference, but it would make a copy (as most would expect) when used as in my sample above.

How can I make `foo` work like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The reference says that it only accepts rvalue reference parameters.

No, this is [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), which could serve as both lvalue reference and rvalue reference, according to the value category of the passed-in argument.

> How can I make `foo` work like this?

The point of declaring a forwarding reference is (1) type deduction is necessary, that means you need to make `foo` a function template here; (2) the parameter `x` has the exact form of `T&&` for the template parameter `T`. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x){
    x = 2;
}
```

then

```
int x = 1;
foo(x);   // lvalue passed, T is deduced as int&, parameter's type is int&
foo(1);   // rvalue passed, T is deduced as int, parameter's type is int&&
```

Note this is true for `std::make_tuple` too, even it's using template parameter pack. And better to bear in mind that even forwarding reference looks like rvalue reference but they're different things.

BTW: [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is usually used with forwarding reference to preserve the value category of the argument e.g. when forwarding it to other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. If instead of an `int`, `foo` needs to accept a `std::string` (or some reference of it), is it good to make `foo` a template for this forwarding behaviour? Anything else not assignable to a `std::string` will not make sense, and should not be passed into `foo`.

Comment: @Bernard In those cases you use `std::enable_if` to constraint `T` to being a `std::string`.

Comment: @Bernard It depends on how you use the parameter inside `foo`; if something wrong passed to `foo` you might get a compilation error. Anyway, forwarding references are designed to be able to accept almost any type of arguments; so if `foo` only works with `std::string`, forwarding references might be over-kill. On the other hand, if you need a more general type, e.g. not only `std::string`, also string literals (`const char[]`), then forwarding reference would be appropriate.

Comment: @songyuanyao That's a good point, it might be better to accept anything assignable to a `std::string`, including a `std::string_view` (C++17).

Comment: @Bernard Yes. Depends on your usage, not only copy may be omitted, but also move; the argument could be used directly, no need to construct a (temporary) `std::string` every time.

Comment: @songyuanyao Could you give me an example? I can't think of any code that will omit move, but will require a copy if the argument is an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is a result of a rather subtle overload of the `&&` operator when it is used with a template parameter:

```
template<typename foo>
void bar(foo &&baz)
```

This is not an rvalue reference. It is a forwarding reference. When the template gets resolved, `baz` is going to be either an lvalue or an rvalue reference, depending on the call situation.

This is why you will see the C++ library provide what appears to be a single template, that works in both lvalue and rvalue contexts.

But forwarding references occur in templates only. In a non-template declaration:

```
void bar(int &&baz)
```

This is always an rvalue reference, and can only be used in rvalue contexts.

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_tuple` works because the function doesn't actually take a rvalue reference like `foo` does.  `std::make_tuple` takes a object in the form of `T&&` and since `T` is a template type it makes it a forwarding reference, not a rvalue reference.  A forwarding reference can bind to lvalues and rvalues where as a rvalue reference can only take a rvalue.  To make `foo` the same you would need

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& bar)
{
    bar = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

void foo(int&& x){
    std::cout<<"rvalue"<<std::endl;
    x = 2;
}

void foo(int& x){
    std::cout<<"lvalue"<<std::endl;
    x = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    foo(x); // no compile error anymore
    foo(std::move(x)); // now r-value is being used        
    std::make_tuple(x); // ok
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```